# jQuery next() td across table rows

Tags: jquery, html-table, calendar, jquery-selectors, tablerow

I have designed a custom calendar using html and jQuery. I want to highlight a range of k days (say 2 days) onhover on the start date. Available dates in my calendar are td of class 'available'. This is the code snippet i am using:

```
$(".monthly-calendar .available").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    $(this).next(".available").toggleClass("selected");
}
```

Unfortunately next() only works for the parent row. This creates a problem when i hover on the last column in a row, in which case i see only 1 column highlighted. How do I overload next() to select available TDs across subsequent rows ?

The fiddle is available on http://jsfiddle.net/yL573/1/ Try hovering on 26th to see the problem. Hovering on 26 should also highlight 27 or the next 'available' td. I want to generalize this for selection of k days (k>1, in this case k=2)

Comment: You will need to show us the html of two rows ..

Comment: Could you post the mark-up of the table you're working with? Otherwise you can only get guesses. Which might be useful, but probably not as specific as you'd like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

could it be something like this?
i made a quick jsfiddle for your concept

it works even over different rows, and even if some days in the middle are already unavailable (not have the class available)

http://jsfiddle.net/dP3Bk/1/

let me know if this is what you expect it to do

it comes down to not taking `.next()` but using the index of the element in the array of all `<td>` elements.

javascript:

```
$('#tableid td.available').hover(function(){
    // mouse in
    var available = $('#tableid td.available');
    var i = available.index($(this));
    $(available[i]).add($(available[i+1])).addClass('current');
}, function(){
    // mouse out
    $('td.current').removeClass('current');
});
```

**remark**
if you have a lot of elements this can be a performance hit. in any case, i'd add the id of the table in front of your selectors, not to work with all `td.available` elements.

Comment: Good solution, but for posterity, please post the relevant JS code in your answer here as well.

Comment: Thanks a tonne Sander, you posted the jsFiddle of the solution before i posted the jsFiddle of the problem !

Answer (score 0):

humble suggestion... check if the element is the (n-1)th child of the row or even the nth child ...if thats the case highlight the nth and the first child of the next row for n-1 and first and second td of next row for nth element... example in a row of 10 cols our element is 9th then 10th and the next rows 1st columns to be set with the selected class.... if the element is 10th check for the last child and select the parent trs next and then its 1st two child td....a conditional should suffice i guess... hope i made sense .....cheers!!

Comment: Nice suggestion, but can we generalize this for k days interval ?